# previous page won't expire

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, expired-sessions

I have a page that has two 'pages' within. Basically it's two DIVs - one is hidden at all times, and it is toggled dependent on a Radio button.

One of these DIVs contains a form which you can submit. I want this whole page, especially that form, refreshed when the user clicks 'back'.

I have tried numerous things, and none of them have worked. Maybe they are in the wrong place?

I currently tried this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); %>
    <%: Response.Expires = -1; %>
```

It still doesn't work. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Since the back button doesn't "reload" the page, this is the problem you are seeing.

You could add a "back button" or "link" which when clicked would obviously reload the page.

Also, look into the javascript onload event.  You might be able to clear the form using that.

Comment: I could, but I want to account for what happens when the user clicks on the actual back button..so the page needs to expire after it posts.

Comment: Not 100% but check to see if the javascript onload event fires.  If so, write code in there that clears out the form.

Comment: I have other JS in there, so I know it fires. I'm not looking to write more code to clear the form, I just need to know why the page is not expiring.

Comment: That's absolutely not helpful at all.